# Gutenberg Block State Value is Resetting on setPreviewDeviceType Update to Desktop

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I am not sure if it's a known issue or not.
Facing this issue when I try to change the preview Desktop from another device type(Mobile, Tablet) state value is resetting to default, I have tested other states, but happening the same.

Please note this is happening for Desktop only not for other devices.

Here is the video
https://youtu.be/lkMzkKjGGPw

I have also tested by setPreviewDeviceType method and default preview button at the top, the same things happening.

```
const { __experimentalSetPreviewDeviceType: setPreviewDeviceType,} = wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post') setPreviewDeviceType(screen);
```

Environment info
WP -6.0 Gutenberg -
Chrome
Desktop on Windows10

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?